# How to replace symlink file?

Tags: android, paypal

I am integrating paypal android sdk in my app.

Like this one http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/10/paypal-android-sdk-with-multiple-in-app.html

It has the below line in the README.md which i can't understand and i am a windows user.

**Windows users need to replace the `libs` symlink file with a copy of the SDK `libs` directory.**

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.x, we've removed the simlinks.  Please use the latest integration instructions from our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/).